# How do I change the position of a quarter circle on the x-axis.

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

I have an equation of a quarter circle that looks like this:
$$y=(3^2-x^2)^{1/2}{{0<x<3}}$$
And I know that I can change the position on the y-axis by adding
$$+3$$
or whatever number instead of "3", but how would I change the position of the Quarter Circle on the x-axis?

Comment: Replacing $x$ by $x-3$ in the equation moves the graph $3$ units to the right, for example.

Comment: Which x? there are two "x" 's used in the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've mentioned, if you want to change the position on the $y$-axis you add to the right hand side, or equivalently replace $y$ with $y - b$.  So, writing $$y - b=(3^2-x^2)^{1/2}\quad \text{for}\quad 0<x<3$$ gives you the upper-right quarter of a circle of radius $3$ centered at the point $(0,b).$  To control the $x$ coordinate of the center we can replace $x$ with $x - a$, which gives us  $$y - b=(3^2-(x-a)^2)^{1/2}\quad \text{for}\quad 0<x-a<3$$ or equivalently, $$y - b=(3^2-(x-a)^2)^{1/2}\quad \text{for}\quad a<x<a+3.$$  This gives you the upper-right quarter of a circle of radius $3$ centered at the point $(a,b)$.  See this [Desmos Plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/r3fgrz0obh) for an interactive version.

Comment: Thank you so much!! And even better, the graph that I was using this equation on and wanted to solve and graph on was indeed Desmos!! So I was able to really understand how to solve this problem!!